# Installing PHP extensions on GCP App Engine

Tags: php, sql-server, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, php-5.6

I've been searching on how add a custom extension`sqlsrv` to my PHP runtime on Google Cloud's App Engine.

After going through the documentation on app engine, I found that there are pre-installed modules and some other modules which can be activated ( https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#enabled_extensions )

But however, I cannot seem to find away to connect to a SQL Server instance as the `sqlsrv_connect` extension is not available and my code base highly depends on it. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Can someone guide me on how to get this extension enabled on my app engine standard environment?

```
error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach for this is to create your own custom runtime and [deploy the Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) with the Dockerfile at the root of your app's folder on App Engine Flex.

As mentioned in the [The PHP Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime) documentation of the App Engine Flex, you can enable an extension by adding a php.ini to the root of your app before deploying it.

For installing the drivers you will need to [extend the runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) by creating a custom one, based on the basic PHP runtime available for App Engine. This will generate a Dockerfile in which you can add the necessary steps to install what you need.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime?hl=fr